# How can I buffer an observable by a simple in Rxjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I would like to buffer an observable by some arbitrary (but simple) criterion. I've set up a simple example here:

```
const observable = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3])
const filtered = observable.filter((n) => n === 3);
observable
  .buffer(filtered)
  .subscribe((n) => {
    // Why is this empty?
    console.log(n);
});
```

### [Bin here](http://jsbin.com/nevaro/edit?html,js,console)

Trying to do this with `filter` only produces an empty array. I am expecting an array of `[1,2,3]`, but that seems to be not how it works. All the documentation for buffer uses asynchronous events like timer, but this isn't what I want. I would simply like to take the last n items based on some arbitrary criterion that I decide.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: if you want to buffer to every 3rd item, you could just use `bufferCount(3)`

Comment: After checking your JSBin it seems like your issue is related to this bugfix here, which seems to be released with the next minor version: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2195

Comment: Sorry, to be clear: the 3 is just an example, so bufferCount is not what I want (it could be any number). I can't get the patch to do what I want but in any case the PR hasn't landed yet, it seems. v4 seems to work, however it emits a final empty array on completion. Is this expected? Bin here: http://jsbin.com/pizugew/edit?html,js,console

Comment: I'm pretty sure its the bug i posted the link to, your behavior is not expected

Comment: So assuming v4, what if I want to release the buffer based on something that's IN the buffer? For example, say that when all numbers in the buffer add up to 6 (could be 0,6 or 1,5, etc) I want to send the collected numbers to the subscribe?

Comment: Your code should work _as is_ in v4 - and after the bugfix is released as well in v5 - your code should actually work finde

Comment: Sorry this was more of a follow up question. Better example here of what I'm expecting to do: http://jsbin.com/xiveki/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You could use `scan` for that, however I would suggest you create a new question for that, since long conversations in the comment-section are not helpful to others who might have the same question

Comment: Good point. I'll try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per olsn's comment, it appears that this was a bug in Rxjs 5. Changing to v4 effectively solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your subscription comes after the values are emitted. If you want it to work:

```
const observable = new Rx.Subject()
const filtered = observable.filter((n) => n === 3);
filtered
  .buffer(filtered)
  .subscribe((n) => {
   console.log(n);
});
Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3]).subscribe(observable);
```

Comment: But this wouldn't connect the buffered observable with the subscribe... or am I missing something?